# In a spark streaming application, how to execute lines.map() function after a block of lines.foreachRDD() completes execution

Tags: java, spark-streaming

In a spark streaming application, how to execute lines.map() function after a block of lines.foreachRDD() completes execution. I'm including a minimal example of what i want:

```
public class Stackoverflow implements Serializable {

    public static List<DummyClass> list = null;

    public void init(String str) throws Exception {
        if (list == null) {
            synchronized (Stackoverflow.class) {
                if (list == null) {
                    list = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        list.add(new DummyClass());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public JavaDStream<DataTuple> initFunction(JavaDStream<DataTuple> lines, final String str) throws Exception {

        lines.foreachRDD(
                new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<DataTuple>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(JavaRDD<DataTuple> dataTupleJavaRDD) throws Exception {
                        init(str);
                    }
                }
        );

        lines.map(new FinalTransformation(list));
        return lines;
    }

}
```

i want lines.map() part of code to execute after the section above it so that list is not null when it executes.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve.
Please explain with some example.
From the example above, it seems like you want to initialize the `list` object only once and when it is initialized you want to use that `list` and apply some kind of transformation on `lines`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running a foreachrdd, run a map that changes the input to the strings you want and the another map. Foreachrdd is not meant for transformation of the rdd, that's what map is for.

```
input.map(init).map(whatever)
```